# Where to create a file for custom filter css code in phalcon 4?

Tags: phalcon

Where to add filter code to minify `CSS` code? Do I need to register a directory, etc.? [Customer Filters Documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/assets#custom-filters) - everything is clear in the documentation, except where to create these custom classes.

What I have already done:

1. installed and configured java
2. downloaded to the server `yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar`
3. created the helpers directory in the same place as the controllers, views
4. registered helpers in the frontend module as follows: `$loader->registerDirs([APP_PATH.'/frontend/helpers/'])->register();`
5. created the file CssYUICompressor.php in the helpers directory and added the class code from the documentation to it
6. I try to run it in the controller like this:

```
$this->assets->collection('header-css')
->addCss('css/base.css', true)
->addCss('css/style.css', true)        
->join(true)
->setSourcePath(APP_PATH . '/')
->setTargetPath(PUBLIC_PATH . '/assets/css/css.'.$this->config->version.'.css')
->setTargetUri('/assets/css/css.'.$this->config->version.'.css')
->addFilter(
    new CssYUICompressor(
    [
        'java-bin'      => '/usr/local/bin/java',
        'yui'           => '/home/yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar',
        'extra-options' => '--charset utf8',
    ]
));
```

but the result is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Frontend\Controllers\CssYUICompressor' not found in /my path/public_html/apps/frontend/controllers/InitController.php
```

**upd**

added to the file CssYUICompressor.php "namespace Frontend\Helpers;"

file CssYUICompressor.php is now:

```
<?php
namespace Frontend\Helpers;

use Phalcon\Assets\FilterInterface;

/**
 * Filters CSS content using YUI
 *
 * @param string $contents
 * @return string
 */
class CssYUICompressor implements FilterInterface
{
    protected $options;

    /**
     * CssYUICompressor constructor
     *
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $contents
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function filter($contents)
    {
        // Write the string contents into a temporal file
        file_put_contents('temp/my-temp-1.css', $contents);

        system(
            $this->options['java-bin'] .
            ' -jar ' .
            $this->options['yui'] .
            ' --type css ' .
            'temp/my-temp-file-1.css ' .
            $this->options['extra-options'] .
            ' -o temp/my-temp-file-2.css'
        );

        // Return the contents of file
        return file_get_contents('temp/my-temp-file-2.css');
    }
}
```

In the module registered as follows:

```
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(
    [
        'Frontend\Controllers' => __DIR__.'/controllers/',
        'Frontend\Models' => __DIR__.'/models/',
        'Frontend\Widgets' => __DIR__.'/widgets/',
        'Frontend\Helpers' => __DIR__.'/helpers/'
    ]
);

$loader->register();
```

I call in the controller now like this:

```
$this->assets->collection('header-css')
->addCss('css/base.css', true)
->addCss('css/style.css', true)        
->join(true)
->setSourcePath(APP_PATH . '/')
->setTargetPath(PUBLIC_PATH . '/assets/css/css.'.$this->config->version.'.css')
->setTargetUri('/assets/css/css.'.$this->config->version.'.css')
->addFilter(
    new \Frontend\Helpers\CssYUICompressor(
    [
        'java-bin'      => '/usr/local/bin/java',
        'yui'           => '/home/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar',
        'extra-options' => '--charset utf8',
    ]
));
```

Now the file is connected, but it produces the following error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Frontend\Helpers\CssYUICompressor::filter($contents) must be compatible with Phalcon\Assets\FilterInterface::filter(string $content): string in /home/devmass/web/dev.loc/public_html/apps/frontend/helpers/CssYUICompressor.php on line 12
```

What more needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

public function filter($contents) => public function filter(string $contents):string